# Child class affects parent class

Tags: php, class

Here is my code:

```
class Parent1
{
    static $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$db = 'a';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent1
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self::$db = 'b';
    }
}

$myParent = new Parent1();
echo $myParent::$db; //"a"

$myChild = new Child();
echo $myChild::$db; //"b"
echo $myParent::$db; //"b" it should be "a"
```

Why `$myParent::$db` is changing to `b`? How to prevent it??

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

```
static $db = null;
```

`$db` is `static`, it's not linked to the instance.
`self::$db = 'b';` will change the unique and shared instance of `$db`.

**How to prevent it?**

You can't. It's how `static` fields work.
By the way, calling `static` from an instance (`$aa::field`) is not a good think.

Take a look at the [documentation about static in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) because you probably don't understand how it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variables. These are class level and shared across all instances. You might want to change them to instance variables... see below.

```
<?php
class Parent1
{
    public $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = 'a';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent1
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = 'b';
    }
}
```

However, writing to $myChild->db WILL change the variable from the parent because it is an inherited variable but it won't affect the $db value from  $myParent.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I redeclare static in Child - now it works.
Thanks for explaining static

```
class Parent1
{
    static $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$db = 'a';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent1
{
    static $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self:$db=parent::$db;
        self::$db = 'b';
    }
}

$myParent = new Parent1();
echo $myParent::$db; //"a"

$myChild = new Child();
echo $myChild::$db; //"b"
echo $myParent::$db; //"a" => as it should
```